# How do you create a process in C that runs after the parent has died?

Tags: c, windows, process, exec

I'm writing a simple program in C which opens an internet browser using the `exec` function. However the program doesn't terminate until I close the internet browser.

What is the best way to write this program so that it opens the internet browser and then ends?

Comment: Windows 7 at the moment, but shouldn't the functionality be the same regardless?

Comment: @DanieL if it was - us programmers wouldnt be paid so much ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `exec`, your entire process is replaced with the image of the new process and the current one ceases to exist. Instead, `fork` a new process beforehand <strike>(and if necessary `setsid` to detach it from it's parent)</strike> and *then* `exec` the new process image. The forked process will be replaced with the new process image and the parent will stay alive. Look into `waitpid` if you want to hold the parent process open until the child exits.

**EDIT:** For future reference, yes, `setsid` is not portable and the semantics around `fork` vary significantly. The spawn-and-execute model still exists on almost every POSIX and non-POSIX platform in some fashion or another even if the host operating system does not explicitly support POSIX.

Comment: Will that work if the OP is on Windows, DOS, Win3.1, Win95, FooBarOS?

Comment: Mostly, yes, by any recent POSIX-supporting operating system. The real question is: is the OP deploying to "Windows, DOS, Windows 3.1, Windows 95, and FooBarOS"? Considering that it's 2012 and it's very unlikely to get any supported Internet Explorer running on any of those platforms, the likely answer is a blatant no. Portability solely for the sake of itself is a completely retarded and utterly pedantic goal.

Comment: Agree that is a bad goal - but so is answering the question before the target OS is known. Or basically the C standard says nothing about this

Comment: Answering the OP with a valid and relatively portable answer for a platform that is slowly but surely reaching POSIX compliance is a bad goal? Would you rather I'd replied with code that only ran on Windows?

Comment: In such an open environment(as it was with NNTP groups) you cannot assume too much. The OP could be using an OS neither of us have ever heard of - assumptions are generally bad. Your answer should be true without constraint. Compilers are pedantic and I think peoples answer should be able to survive pedantic scrutiny. ie 'It returns an integer' - pedant stuff 'how many bits', 'what bit order' etc

Comment: Of course the C standard says nothing about it: it hasn't got anything to do with the C language. Manipulating processes of a running operating system is obviously implementation-defined.

Comment: My point exactly :-) you answered the question before you knew which implementation was being used (but you guessed correctly)

Comment: @AdrianCornish: If he's recommending `fork` and `setsid`, I'd say he guessed incorrectly.  Neither of those work as expected on Windows.

Comment: You can judge any answer according to "pedantic scrutiny" but at the end of the day, how many operating systems in general use in 2012 (mostly) support POSIX and Internet Explorer at the same time? Pedantry is stupid. EDIT: @BenVoigt is correct. `setsid` isn't portable, and `fork` can vary. The general idea remains the same regardless of the functions used.

Comment: @BenVoigt I stand corrected - Thanks Ben - but it still validates my point about Joshua's answer.

Comment: @JoshuaK: I'm not sure why you're on this "Internet Explorer" kick.  The question doesn't mention that or any other browser.  In fact, it wasn't until DanieL commented on my answer that he intends to ignore the user's configured browser settings, that I would suspect he means IE (since that's the only browser likely to be on all Windows 7 systems).

Comment: @JoshuaK Now you are showing your limited experience with the computer world. There are thousands of OS's and there are thousands of CPU's that these OS'es run on. If you answer a question on a public forum it must be correct for every possible variant within the parameters that you specify in your answer. Simple example in C - where does the output of stdout go when its running on a dishwasher?

Comment: @BenVoigt I could have sworn the OP wrote "Internet Explorer" in the question body about five minutes ago.

Comment: It's a utility I'm writing for myself, it needs to be able to open several different internet browsers. The paths are configurable though.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't seem to support fork, presumably because it's so difficult to implement on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Call the [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) API, passing the URL (not the path to the browser!)

That will spawn the user's preferred browser and return immediately.

Then call `ExitProcess`, which will terminate your program.  The browser will remain running.

There's also [the `spawn`* functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx), but it's not recommended to use those for web pages, since they open a particular application rather than respecting the user's browser preference.  But for your personal use, go right ahead.  Like `ShellExecute`, `spawn` can return immediately so you can `exit()` the parent process, use the `_P_NOWAIT` or `_P_DETACH` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to pick the browser, and I also might want to run this on other platforms at some point, so I would prefer not to use the Windows APIs.

Comment: @DanieL: The user didn't specify his browser preference just so you could ignore it.  If I ran a program and it opened Internet Explorer, it'd be uninstalled.

Comment: It's a utility program for me to use. It needs to be able to open several different internet browsers.

Comment: @DanieL: Read the documentation I linked.  You can pass an executable name (and its arguments in a separate parameter).  Or use one of the `spawn` functions for increased portability.

Answer (score 0):

DanieL -

I agree with Ben's answer (he even got my upvote) because that's precisely what I would have answered with.

However, if you want to launch a specific browser, or in other words, a specific application, then just call the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Read the MSDN documentation very carefully. It's a tricky API to get right.  Example code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I didn't update my answer because `ShellExecute` works just fine for launching .exe files as well.  And nowhere near as complicated as `CreateProcess`.

Comment: My question was not "How do I open an internet browser in Windows?". I wanted to know how to execute another program (in this example, an internet browser), and have my program end without waiting for the other program to close.
I also might want to use this on *nix at a later date so don't want to use Windows APIs when I can use `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: @DanieL - Have you looked at the "system" function call.  Might be the most portable thing, but I haven't tried it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx  Otherwise, Windows and UNIX are different beasts. If you need to make your code truly portable, then you will likely be writing some shim functions that abstract out the differences.

Comment: The system function creates an instance of the default shell to run a given command, that isn't necessary for what I want to do. `fork` and `exec` work well for me on Windows and *nix.

Comment: @DanieL: Visual Studio doesn't seem to support fork.  What development platform are you using?

Comment: At the moment Windows, using nano and gcc.